# Group objects of same kind C#

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a list of objects that are keyed off or identified uniquely by one of their properties say "ID". I need to group all the objects of different ID's that will have rest of properties the same.

Example: Obj has properties "ID", "E1", "E2" , "E3". Note these are all properties of the Obj.

I know ID's are different for all List of Obj's, but would like to group if E1,E2 and E3 are same for different Obj's. So I would have array of Obj's that have same E1,E2,E3 but different ID's.

What's the easiest way of handling this in C#, any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, something like this would work with LINQ:

```
var groups = collections.GroupBy(x => new { x.E1, x.E2, x.E3 });
```

That will give you a sequence of groupings you can iterate over. For example:

```
var groups = collections.GroupBy(x => new { x.E1, x.E2, x.E3 });
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}", group.Key);
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  ID: {0}", item.ID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement an Interface of common properties/methods between the objects. Use the interface type for interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Linq sounds good to me.

```
public class YourClass
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string E1 { get; set; }
    public string E2 { get; set; }
    public string E3 { get; set; }
}

public static YourClass[] GetClassArray(IEnumerable<YourClass> objects)
{
    return objects.OrderBy<YourClass, string>(c => c.E1)
                  .ThenBy<YourClass, string>(c => c.E2)
                  .ThenBy<YourClass, string>(c => c.E3)
                  .ThenBy<YourClass, string>(c => c.ID)
                  .ToArray<YourClass>();
}
```

Comment: this does *ordering* and not grouping

Comment: @BrokenGlass This does ordering which incidentally does grouping, in a more generic sense.  I'll admit readily, though, that @Jon Skeet kicks me on this one, as would be expected, and that this may not be the _best_ way to go about things.

Comment: You're ordering by ID *first* though, which means it's not usefully grouping by E1, E2 and E3 at all. If you were ordering by ID *last* then you could use those ordered results and spot when the E1/E2/E3 tuple changed, but as it is I don't think this is a useful answer to the question.